# Custom CSS File Not Rendered in Blade View

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have some problems here. My View in Laravel Projects won't rendered the custom css but, it's only rendered the `bootstrap.min.css` by using bootstrap CDN in the layouts. Here is the code from the view that not get rendered :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('banner')
<div class="position-relative overflow-hidden text-center bg-light">
    <!-- Carousel Headline -->
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" cl  ass="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel Indicator -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

In order to calling that view, i'm using controller like this :

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('products.show')->with('product', $product);
    }
```

and this is my code in the layouts :

```
    <!-- Banner Part Start -->
    <section class="banner_part">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col">
                    @yield('banner')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

so anyone knows what's wrong in my codes?

Comment: Have you tried to put `!important` behind each of the custom css?

Comment: where do you have the css referenced? I see you are using the custom class but i don't see the reference (the link tag), maybe there's something wrong with it

Comment: I'm including the custom css file in the layouts header `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/productpage.css">`.

Comment: I've also tried to put the `!important`, and it's still not working.

Comment: Is the CSS file found (no 404 errors for example)? And maybe you can check in your browser developer window if the CSS is overwritten, or maybe it's a CSS issue (like a wrong selector), and not a Laravel problem at all.